# How to display Summary statistics next to a plot using matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a function that will iterate over the list of numerical features in a dataframe to display histogram and summary statistics next to it. I am using `plt.figtext()` to display the statistics but I am getting an error

```
num_features=[n1,n2,n3]

for i in num_features:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.hist(df[i])
    plt.figtext(1,0.5,df[i].describe() )
    ax.set_title(i)
    plt.show()
```

When I do this I get an error/warning message:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

It works fine if use `df[n].mean()` instead of `describe()`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to print a plot and show some statistics next to it?

Comment: `df[n].describe()` returns a dataframe, while `df[n].mean()` returns a number. `plt.figtext` takes floats, not dataframes. You'll probably have to add each statistic individually, without using `describe()`. That shouldn't be too hard though :)

Comment: That's what I thought.. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can "simplify" your code, by formatting the dataframe returned by `describe()` as a string using `to_string()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(2000,)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(df[0])
plt.figtext(0.1,0.5, df.describe().to_string())
plt.figtext(0.75,0.5, df.describe().loc[['mean','std']].to_string())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the solution above, the text formatting messes up a little bit. To fix this, I added a workaround, where we divide the description into two figures, which are then aligned.

The helper:

```py
def describe_helper(series):
    splits = str(series.describe()).split()
    keys, values = "", ""
    for i in range(0, len(splits), 2):
        keys += "{:8}\n".format(splits[i])
        values += "{:>8}\n".format(splits[i+1])
    return keys, values
```

Now plot the graph:

```
demo = np.random.uniform(0,10,100)
plt.hist(demo, bins=10)
plt.figtext(.95, .49, describe_helper(pd.Series(demo))[0], {'multialignment':'left'})
plt.figtext(1.05, .49, describe_helper(pd.Series(demo))[1], {'multialignment':'right'})
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you also want to save the figtext when saving the image, change the bbox_inches:

```
plt.savefig('fig.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this based on feedback  and it works fine now.

```
for i in num_cols:
#calculate number of bins first based on Freedman-Diaconis rule
    n_counts=df[i].value_counts().sum()
    iqr=df[i].quantile(0.75)-df[i].quantile(0.25)
    h = 2 * iqr * (n_counts**(-2/3))
    n_bins=(df[i].max()-df[i].min()).round(0).astype(np.int64)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.hist(df[i],bins=15)
    plt.figtext(1,0.5,s=t[i].describe().to_string())
    plt.show()
```