# Summary Statistics on Seaborn Plot in Dynamic Location or Just Out of the Way?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I want to display summary statistics on seaborn plots for presentation purposes.

This is a function I'm creating so the underlying data/distribution will change, therefore I need a way to either dynamically change where the summary stats are displayed or have them shown in a place where they will never be in the way.

If the answer given is to have the summary statistics always on the top right side of the image outside of the graphing area, that would be acceptable for my use.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029140/how-to-display-summary-statistics-next-to-a-plot-using-matplotlib-or-seaborn) solution, but the location of the descriptive statistics are hard coded:

[image]

Here's my simplified code:

```
my_list = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
my_series = pd.Series(my_list)
sns.histplot(data = my_series, stat = 'probability')
plt.figtext(0.1,0.5, my_series.describe().to_string())
plt.title(my_title)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib has auto "out of the way" placement built into its legend, so a hack could be:

```py
my_list = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
my_series = pd.Series(my_list)
ax = sns.histplot(data = my_series, stat = 'probability')

handles = [plt.Line2D([], [], visible=False) for _ in labels]
labels = [f"{stat}: {val:.2f}" for stat, val in my_series.describe().items()]

ax.legend(
    handles,
    labels,
    loc="best",
    handlelength=0,
)
```

[image]